# What are the root systems for the n-dimensional torus?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

My question may seem silly at first, but currently I am not able to work out the question of finding all roots for the n-dimensional torus. At first, it seemed obvious to me that there are no roots at all. However, after trying to prove it I got stuck. Let us consider the 1-dimensional torus ( circle). The roots are simultaneous eigenvalues of the differential operators associated to the basis of maximal cartan subalgebra. What is the Lie algebra of the 1-dim torus at neutral element? Apparently, it is real line. What is multiplication in this algebra and all the stupid questions like that. I am lost in these small silly problems and can't answer the initial question ?

Comment: I will be happy to know all the dominant integral elements for the n-dimensional torus and how the Killing form looks on this group.

Comment: An $n$-dimensional torus is an abelian group. Hence its Lie algebra is also abelian, i.e. the Lie bracket is always zero.

Comment: Then the system of roots is empty. But what about the set $\Sigma$ of dominant integral elements? Can I claim that for the $n$-dimensional torus $$\Sigma=\mathbb{Z}^n$$ ?

Comment: What is a *dominant integral element*?

Comment: It is the highest weight of a representation. Partial order is given by the system of positive roots. Since there are no roots, any weight will be the highest one. Am i mistaken?

Comment: I though that dominant is always relative to a system of positive roots, so it becomes meaningless, when there are no roots. But sure, the $n$-dimensional torus has 1-dimensional representations of any weight. I'm not sure I would call those "highest weights" in this case when there is no order relation.